# Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-slick-carousel', **PATH** implicitly has an 'any'

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have Vue app, and try add vue-slick-carousel module and i have this warning:

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsYOA.png)

Error text - Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-slick-carousel', **PATH** implicitly has an 'any'

**I don't use TS on my project.**

I try add TS to project and use this command `npm i --save-dev @types/vue-slick-carousel`, but it don't work and i remove TS form project.

All solutions what i found was with TS using, but i don't need it at the moment.

**UPDATE**
When I add library to project I have warnings in console ([warnings screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFrQd.png))

```
<template>
        <VueSlickCarousel>
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
        </VueSlickCarousel>
    </template>
    <script>
    import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
    import VueSlickCarousel from 'vue-slick-carousel'
    
    export default {
        components: { VueSlickCarousel },
    }
```

Comment: does your file with the error have a `.ts` extension?  If so, change it to `.js`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @yoduh no, i haven't any `.ts` file. 
I don't understand why he advice me add new declaration `.d.ts`, i don't use `TS` on project

Comment: Programming languages like TS don't generate errors in your IDE.  That's your IDE's doing. The actual error comes from a **TS service** running in your IDE, possibly from an extension, e.g. Volar.  Why it's producing a TS error in a JS file is hard to say without knowing more about your specific IDE environment.

Comment: @yoduh I use VS Code. Yeah, i understand, this warning by extension. But library don't add to project... 
I added some information to my main question.